# How default constructor knows where to initialize the default values of the data member in memory

Tags: c++, constructor

From book "**The first hidden argument to the constructor is the this pointer**"
Now when we write like

```
classname object;
```

Is it like first memory for the object is created and address of the object is pass to default constructor so that it can initializes the values of the class.

If this is the concept for object how memory is created, is it created by the OS ?

Comment: C++ has an 'as if' rule, which basically means you cannot say exactly how it works. It's 'as if' the memory for the object is created and then the address passed to the constructior, but whether your program really works that way is impossible to say. So think about it that way if it helps, but it may be different in reality.

Comment: What is the book by the way?

Comment: Thinking in c++

Comment: It's a good book (for free), look at chapter 1 'Creating and Destroying Objects'

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you write your definition:

- If you define your object at global scope the linker will figure out where to place the object in the program’s data area and make sure there is enough space. The same is true for all static objects, independent of whether they are static class members or function local statics.
- If you define your object as a local object in a function it will be placed on the stack. The calling conventions on the system in use will arrange for enough space on the stack (assuming there is enough space on the stack to start with; otherwise you’d get a stack overflow).
- If your definition is actually a member declaration, space for the object will be made in the containing object and the new object will be placed there.
- Just for completeness, when using a `new` expression the space is allocated on the heap and the object is places there.
- Another case are thread local objects which are placed somewhere on the thread’s stack.

Note that the placement of objects applies to all constructors: the only significance of the default constructor is that you don’t pass any arguments when constructing the object.

Answer (score 1):

As John mentioned in the comments, there is no explicit information in the Standard on how the memory is allocated/managed. However, assuming that no compiler optimizations take place and that you are creating an object on the stack... then this will *likely* happen.

Given:

```
void f()
{
    foo x;
}
```

The compiler will produce something like:

```
void f()
{
    char foo_buffer[sizeof(foo)];
    new (&foo_buffer) foo()
    reinterpret_cast<foo*>(foo_buffer)->~foo();
}
```

The space for a `foo` instance is reserved on the stack, then the constructor is called on that space. At the end of the scope, the destructor is called.

Answer (score -2):

When an object is created, the os will Create the space.when the object is created the os automatically calls the default constructor .

Comment: Really better to say your *program* allocates the space and calls the constructor.